# Implementing Twitch Gem into Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitch-api

I am still a bit new with Ruby On Rails I managed to connect a youtube API without issues for pulling live streams. Now I am trying to do the same with Twitch and I found this gem https://github.com/mauricew/ruby-twitch-api . I am just confused as to where this part goes

```
twitch_client = Twitch::Client.new(
  client_id: client_id,
  client_secret: client_secret,

  ## this is default
  # token_type: :application,

  ## this can be required by some Twitch end-points
  # scopes: scopes,

  ## if you already have one
  # access_token: access_token
)
```

I already registered it with Twitch and have my client id and client secret. I would like to first run it via `bin/rails c` just to test everything. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add your code snippet directly in the console, and the you can use `twitch_client` to use the API.

Note that you'll need access to this `twitch_client` to use it, or to create another instance

Answer (score 0):

And on whether where you should put this code snippet. You can put it in a initializer in rails. So you will have the following:

```
config/initializers/twitch_client.rb
```

Link that is similar to yours:
[Rails initializer](https://medium.com/@jelaniwoods/rails-initializers-13db175c0f1e)